# Stalling the cmd prompt till a download is complete

Tags: python, cmd, wait

I am trying to download and install python from the command prompt. I have both the download and install commands. The problem is I want the cmd to wait until the download is over and then go for the install commands.

I am doing the above thing using a python script and its subprocess module thus my code looks something like this (these are not the exact commands):

```
subprocess.call('start /max http://profile.org/choice/fileW.msi' , shell = True)
subprocess.call('msiexec.exe fileW.msi' , shell = True)
```

The first line downloads the python.msi file. The second line installs python.msi. When I run them separately they work but when I run them together I get "fileW.msi not found". The reason is that before the .msi gets downloaded, cmd runs the second command and as a result, it can't find the file as it is yet to be downloaded.

Comment: More voodoo programming. Why would your cut and paste code from idiots work?

Comment: @ACatInLove I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with CMD.

Comment: @ACatInLove I don't agree. `start` is built-in in CMD, commands are using `shell=True`. That makes 2 reasons. Can `cmd` can be avoided? Yes, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General answer: since you need `/max` you need `start`, but `start` starts in background, unless you use the `/wait` switch

But in your case, that won't work, because the string is an URL and windows chooses your default browser to open / download it, so you cannot block the call until download has ended.

Another solution would be to use the [`wget`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget) package:

```
import wget
downloaded_file = wget.download("http://profile.org/choice/fileW.msi")
subprocess.call(['msiexec.exe',downloaded_file])
```

Comment: So this will hold the execution of the next command (install command) till the first (download command) is completed?

Comment: Or even a better and "safe" solution, use python to do the download the file instead of relying on 3rd party software. Take a look at [urllib.urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)

Comment: @LohmarASHAR good idea. note that there's a python wget package as well. my answer relies on that one, but urlretrieve also works.

Comment: @SunandaSaha I made some more tests and I edited my answer. You may have to install wget package with "pip install wget" if not available.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry I've miss-read your comment, I thought your referring to the "wget" command line tool. Then using an "external package" (which you have to install) vs using an "internal package" (that's already in the standard installation) is a matter of choice and/or taste.

Comment: @LohmarASHAR TBH I already used wget successfully in the past that's why I used that. But yes, using a package you don't need to fetch on pip is a plus.